# My snake's stomache burst two days after eating a pinky

Tags: diet, snakes

I had a baby corn snake and unfortunately two days after feeding her a pinky her stomach burst. It turned black and there was a blister over her stomach where it burst. What should I do?

Comment: Take her to the veterinarian ASAP.

Comment: The condition you describe could be indicative of an urgent or emergency health issue, please contact your vet for direction on how soon your pet needs to be seen. If someone knowledgeable in first aid is available, they may be able to write an answer, but you should not wait.

Answer (score 2):

Take her to the vet immediately! It has to be corrected by surgery or else toxins will leak into her body and she will die.